# Docusign checkbox is invisible

Tags: checkbox, docusignapi

I add two checkbox using java SDK. One uses AnchorString relative position, one uses absolute position. Somehow the one use absolute position just be invisible. The codes to create the two tabs:

```
    Checkbox checkbox = new Checkbox();
    checkbox.setTabLabel("chkLabel");
    checkbox.setPageNumber("1");
    checkbox.setAnchorString("관련");
    checkbox.setAnchorXOffset("-10");
    checkbox.setAnchorYOffset("-10");

    Checkbox checkbox2 = new Checkbox();
    checkbox2.setTabLabel("chkLabel2");
    checkbox2.setPageNumber("1");
    checkbox2.setXPosition("100");
    checkbox2.setYPosition("100");

    List<Checkbox> checkboxTabs = new ArrayList<Checkbox>();
    checkboxTabs.add(checkbox);
    checkboxTabs.add(checkbox2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the document on which you want the checkbox to appear on.
Use the property `documentId` that will contain the Id of the document on which you want the checkbox to appear on.

[image]

[Source](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Checkbox%20Tab.htm)